# How to convert dB back to manitude and then to rectangular format

Tags: fourier-transform, audio, python, stft

I am experimenting with audio (wav files) using Short-Time Fourier Transform (STFT) in `Python` using `scipy.signal.stft`. 
As I understand we get data for `freq`, `time` and `magnitude` + `phase` in `rectangular` format.
for e.g. (shortened for illustration)

```
freq, time, Zxx = scipy.signal.stft(signal, fs=fs , .. and some other parms)
```

If I take a single value from `Zxx` , e.g.

```
x = -0.01224990-0.01877387j ,
```

I would like to convert this value to `dB`, do some modification such as

- add/reduce few dB's
- Also change angle or phase
- and reconstruct the value back to `x`

So far I have,

```
#Magnitude
m = np.abs(-0.01224990-0.01877387j)
0.022416918717497732

#angle in degrees
ad =np.angle(-0.01224990-0.01877387j, deg=True)
-123.12434072219258

#phase 
cmath.phase(-0.01224990-0.01877387j)
-2.1489251349495935

#magnitude in dB
dB = 20*np.log10(abs(p))
-32.988481658150704

#modified magnitude
dB = dB + 10.0

#Modified angle
ad = -123.12434072219258 + 50.0
```

Now, How do I convert it back to **modified** `x`. using above values?

I researched but couldn't find a straightforward solution. Before reinventing the wheel of constructing the complex mathematical functions, i thought I would ask the experts.

The only reference I found was `mag2db` and `db2mag` at `matlab`, but not sure how to access or implement these in `python`.

**EDIT1**
Please note: I am not trying to reconstruct original signal (or `x` value) back. I need to modify `Zxx` values and hence I know I will get a different signal back using `scipy.signal.istft`.

Although I can directly manipulate `x+jy` which affect both `magnitude` and `phase`, I would like to modify them individually and Hence this question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Converting mel spectrogram to spectrogram <- Does not solve my problem as the linked question is to convert spectrogram back. I am trying to understand how to convert a magnitude + phase back to rectangular entity (x + jy) using python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X_\mathrm{db} = 20 \cdot \mathrm{log}_{10}(|X|)$, then $|X| = 10^{X_\mathrm{db} / 20}$, of course. Furthermore, you can compute the cartesian representation of a complex number $c = a + ib$ from its magnitude $|c|$ and phase $\varphi$:  $c = |c| \cdot \mathrm{exp}(i \varphi)$

So you are probably looking for something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fs = 100
t = np.arange(100)
x = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 3 * t / fs)

X = np.fft.fft(x)
X_mag = np.abs(X)
X_db = 20 * np.log10(X_mag)
X_phase = np.angle(X)

# ... do modification on X_db and X_phase ...

X_mag_rec = 10 ** (X_db / 20)
X_rec = X_mag_rec * np.exp(1j * X_phase)
x_rec = np.real(np.fft.ifft(X_rec))

plt.plot(t, x, label='original')
plt.plot(t, x_rec, label='reconstructed')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

If you are doing the modification in the STFT domain, note there may be no valid inverse STFT. For details on that look into:

D. Griffin, J. Lim: *Signal estimation from modified short-time Fourier transform*, in: *IEEE Transactions on Acoustics, Speech, and Signal Processing*, vol. 32, no. 2, pp. 236–243, Apr 1984.